Unable to Deploy Google Apps Script – (Error: 'Something went wrong. Please reload the page to try again.')
I am facing an issue with deploying my Google Apps Script project. I have been granted full permissions, including the Editor and Owner roles, but I still cannot deploy the script. The error message I receive is:
"Something went wrong. Please reload the page to try again."
Here are some important details:

I have two accounts: one is connected to Google Workspace and has the Editor role on the project, while the other is not connected to Google Workspace but has the Owner role.
Despite having the Owner role on one account, the only account that can deploy the project is the one who originally created the project and granted me the permissions.
I am trying to deploy the script as a web app, and the script is linked to Google Sheets.
The project owner (the person who created the project) is the only one able to deploy the script, while both my Editor and Owner accounts are unable to do so.
I’ve tried using different browsers, clearing the cache, and confirming all the permissions, but the issue persists.

Could anyone shed light on why this permission conflict might be occurring or offer a solution? It seems like there might be an issue with the deployment permissions related to the original project creator, even for accounts with Owner access.
Thank you for your help!

The web app can only be published on an account that has the same domain as the owner of the file. It's possible to share the script with users outside the domain, allowing them to access and possibly modify it. However, they won't be able to deploy it as a web app and would likely encounter some sort of error. This information is hinted at Web Apps, where it states that Web apps deployed in one domain cease to function if their ownership changes to a shared drive or account in a different domain.

You may want to try the answer in this Stack Overflow post where they made a copy of the spreadsheet file and, when the process is repeated on it, got an authorization screen and the Webapp was successfully deployed.
